# Sendmail says email sent but it's not getting delivered

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

Sorry I'm new to this forum, I have setup sendmail on my Ubuntu 20.04 server I run on my own remote server, when I send a form from my website it says sent successfully but it never arrives to the person. I have got the info from the mail.log but hopping someone can point me in the right direction of what needs editing to get it to work. I'm guessing it's a relay issue but just need to know which file needs editing.

**This is the log from the Mail.log file**

> Jan  3 09:41:01 socialchat sm-msp-queue[7606]: **unable to qualify my
> own domain name (localhost)** -- using short name
>
> Jan  3 09:45:29 socialchat sm-mta[7232]: 1038meNC006241:
> to=andrew@nxxxxxxxx.me, delay=00:56:49, xdelay=00:10:55,
> mailer=esmtp, pri=300752, relay=alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
> [173.194.192.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: **Connection timed out with
> alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.**
>
> Jan  3 09:45:30 socialchat sm-mta[7232]: 1035wSJt002356:
> to=andrew@nxxxxx.me, delay=03:47:02, xdelay=00:00:00,
> mailer=esmtp, pri=840760, relay=alt4.aspmx.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0,
> stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> Jan  3 09:45:30 socialchat sm-mta[7232]: 10340Wld001023:
> to=andrew@naxxxxx.me, delay=05:44:58, xdelay=00:00:00,
> mailer=esmtp, pri=1470747, relay=alt4.aspmx.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0,
> stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> Jan  3 09:50:47 socialchat sm-mta[7036]: 1038hDDQ006143:
> to=andrew@naxxxxxx.me, delay=01:07:34, xdelay=00:10:55,
> mailer=esmtp, pri=300757, relay=alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
> [173.194.192.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with
> alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> Jan  3 09:50:47 socialchat sm-mta[7036]: 1035wSJt002356:
> to=andrew@nxxxxxx.me, delay=03:52:19, xdelay=00:00:00,
> mailer=esmtp, pri=930760, relay=alt3.aspmx.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0,
> stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> Jan  3 09:50:47 socialchat sm-mta[7036]: 1035las9002245:
> 1039Ddmf007036: sender notify: Warning: could not send message for
> past 4 hours

Comment: Most likely your ISP is blocking outbound connections on port 25.  Also check your firewall.

Comment: Thank you, I have opened port 25 on my server but will check with the company that the server is hosted with to see if they block port 25

Comment: Note: Stack Exchange sites are **not** forums. They are Q&A platforms not open for ongoing discussions. Specific questions which return specific answers only. [ask]